# Prevent pictures from being pasted into contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to prevent pictures from being pasted into a content editable `<div>`. I have already tried the following but it doesn't filter out pictures, it only removes the styling of words.

```
div.addEventListener("paste", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

How can i prevent it from happening without using the HTML textarea element?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question seems specific and the questions marked as duplicate don't seem to specifically answer this question.
As I cannot add an answer, I'm pasting my solution:

`if (event.clipboardData.types.includes('Files')) event.preventDefault()`